# How can I pull specific database row which has specific row value but the row value is in array?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this database row from where I need to pull the database row only with specific row value such as template_number == 'template-1'. And the row value is in array similar to this

```
a:1:{s:11:"design";a:5:{s:19:"style";s:7:"default";s:15:"template_number";s:10:"template-4";s:20:"custom_template_type";s:1:"1";s:14:"menu_placement";s:5:"right";}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sounded like you want to pick a row which have value that you desire, so maybe its like this :

`select * from table where column1='value'`

and you will get data by text formated